# ButterKnife error when using in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, butterknife

I'm using ButterKnife library in my android application. It works fine in Activities. But when I use that in Fragment it give me an error while building the project. Here is my code :

```
package com.foxastudios.stopnosocomials.Fragments;

public class FragmentObserveeOne extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.text_obs_one_name) TextView obsName;

    public FragmentObserveeOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_observee_one, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,rootView);

        obsName.setText("TEXT");

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

My fragments are in a separate package named Fragments. And here is the errors that I get:

```
Error:(8, 39) error: cannot find symbol class Fragments
Error:(13, 65) error: package Fragments does not exist
Error:(27, 59) error: package Fragments does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the package contains a capital letter. As the Java docs describe - [All packages should use lowercase letters.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the
>   names of classes or interfaces.

Renaming the package `fragments` should fix your issue.

Finally, please check the latest [Butterknife docs](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to see how to use Butterknife correctly with `Fragment` classes to avoid memory leaks as your code at present does not use an `Unbinder`. The 'BINDING RESET' section of the docs should point you in the right direction.